# How to know file size of translated SVF file in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I have using for forge API services for Revit and Naviswork files display. In that how to check translated SVF file size.
Please provide the solution to check file size of translated SVF file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you load a model of the Viewer, it will show the memory used (see console output). As the viewer loads files on demand, the total SVF size (on disk) should not affect your app.

[image]